# Explicit decomposition of the regular representation of a finite group

Tags: representation-theory

It is known that if $G$ is a finite group then the regular representation $\mathbf{C}[G]$ decomposes as
$$
\mathbf{C}[G] = \bigoplus_{\pi} \pi^{\text{dim}(\pi)}
$$
where $\pi$ ranges over all irreducible representations of $\pi$.

My question is : is there an explicit way to understand this isomorphism? In particular if I give you such a $\pi$  can you then tell me how I can explicitely embed $\pi$ in $\mathbf{C}[G]$

When $\pi$ is of dimension $1$ it is easy to do cf. [How does one decompose the regular representation of the group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606034/how-does-one-decompose-the-regular-representation-of-the-group)

In my case I am really interested in a representation of dimension 2 (but for an abstract G). So if this helps feel free to assume this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may go without saying, but I'd like to first mention that Wedderburn-Artin gives this decomposition as part of the theorem: it says

$$\mathbb{C}[G]\cong M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\times\cdots\times M_{n_r}(\mathbb{C})$$

Now each irrep of $G$ (say with a left action) has isotypic component in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ given by one of these factors, $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ for some $i$.  It follows that to each irrep of $G$ we get a central idempotent $e_i$ in the group ring such that $\mathbb{C}[G]e_i=M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$.  In particular, if you can find this central idempotent then you can generate the isotypic component of this irrep inside $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

Now, if that doesn't make you happy, then another thing I can think of is that for any rep $V$ of $G$, each irrep $\pi$ of $G$ has a canonical projector $\sigma_\pi:V\to V$ which projects $V$ onto the $\pi$-isotypic component of $V$.  Applying this construction to $\mathbb{C}[G]$ would allow you to construct the $\pi$-isotypic component in $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

Explicitly, if $\chi_{\pi}$ is the character of $\pi$, then this projector is given by the formula:

$$\sigma_\pi=\frac{n_\pi}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}\chi_{\pi}(g^{-1})g$$

where $n_\pi=\dim_\mathbb{C}\pi$.  In fact, as an element of the group ring this is just $e_\pi$, the central idempotent associated to $\pi$ (which is the only thing it could be if you think about it).

Comment: I don't understand most of your argument. What about "[A given linear representation $\rho:G\to\text{GL}(W)$ is isomorphic to the (left-regular) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Left-_and_right-regular_representation) if and only if there exists a $w\in W$ such that $(\rho(s)w)_{s\in G}$ is a basis of $W$". What could be $w$ here ?

Comment: Then $w$ would be 1 in the group ring, i.e. the sum of the central idempotents $e_1+\dots+e_r$.

Comment: Also, if you could say which part(s) of the argument you're confused about, that would be very helpful.

Comment: In your argument, are you seing somewhere the representations of $G$ a [subalgebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Representations.2C_modules_and_the_convolution_algebra) of [$\mathbb{C}[G]$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html) ?

Comment: I mean... I guess they turn out to be something like subalgebras of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, although they aren't really subalgebras since they don't contain $1$.  But I'm thinking of them as left ideals in the group ring, or equivalently left submodules of the group ring.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that it is indeed very helpful. But I wonder, is there a way to get each individual copy of $\pi$ and not just the isotypic component ? I imagine it won't be canonical but still I wonder if something can be said.

Comment: I don't know of a canonical copy of each $\pi$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ that is coordinate free.  If we write down an isomorphism as in Wedderburn-Artin, then each column of a $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ will be a copy of the irrep corresponding to this factor.